# How to calculate difference among every item within a group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
   team player  metric_a  metric_b
0   1   player1   15        25
1   1   player2   20        30
2   1   player3   21        12
3   2   player4   9         46
4   2   player5   39         5
```

How could we compute the (absolute) difference of every player with every other player of the **same team**?

Output:

```
    team  player_a player_b metric_a_diff metric_b_diff
0    1    player1  player2         5             10  
1    1    player1  player3         6             13
2    1    player2  player3         1             18
3    2    player4  player5         30            41
```

I have tried something along the lines of:

```py
from itertools import combinations

combos = lambda s : pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(s.values, 2)), columns=['player_a', 'player_b'])


df.groupby('team')['player'].apply(combos).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

but I don't know how to get `diff` in to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try something new...self `merge` the dataframe on `team` to create all possible combinations then calculate the diff by subtracting the columns from left and right dataframes

```
s = df.reset_index()
s = (
    s.merge(s, on='team')
     .query('index_y > index_x') # remove duplicate combinations
     .drop(columns=['index_x', 'index_y']) # drop unwanted columns
)

s['metric_a_diff'] = s.pop('metric_a_y').sub(s.pop('metric_a_x')).abs()
s['metric_b_diff'] = s.pop('metric_b_y').sub(s.pop('metric_b_x')).abs()
```

Result

```
    team player_x player_y  metric_a_diff  metric_b_diff
1      1  player1  player2              5              5
2      1  player1  player3              6             13
5      1  player2  player3              1             18
10     2  player4  player5             30             41
```

Comment: creative solution!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thanks for answering - it's quite interesting indeed :-) How would you approach the case where many metrics exist? Would you do a for loop maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a solution based on [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) that works with an arbitrary number of columns:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combine(g):
    # get indices of combinations
    a, b = map(list, zip(*combinations(g.index, r=2)))
    
    # slice left/right part
    d1 = g.loc[a].reset_index(drop=True)
    d2 = g.loc[b].reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='team')
    
    # compute absolute difference and combine
    return pd.concat([d1[['team', 'player']], d2['player'],
                      d1.drop(columns=['team', 'player'])
                        .sub(d2.drop(columns='player')).abs()
                     ], axis=1)

out = df.groupby('team').apply(combine).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
   team   player   player  metric_a  metric_b
0     1  player1  player2         5         5
1     1  player1  player3         6        13
2     1  player2  player3         1        18
3     2  player4  player5        30        41
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['player_a', 'player_b','metric_a_diff','metric_b_diff'])
def combos(ls):
    for i,j in enumerate(ls):
        if i%2==0:
            new.loc[len(new)] =[j[0],ls[i+1][0], abs(j[1]-ls[i+1][1]), abs(j[2]-ls[i+1][2])]

df.groupby('team')[['player','metric_a','metric_b']].apply(lambda p : combos([l for ls in list(combinations(p.values, 2)) for l in ls]))
new
```